# How can I retrieve the check-in object from foursquare by querying with a checkin id?

Tags: foursquare, checkin

I have obtained the 4sq checkin id from twitter streaming api and I want to get the details of the checkin such as userid, time, venueid etc.

However, when I check the 4sq api, I find that the related endpoint requires an acting user. So can anybody suggest what could be an alternative way to get this information? (especially user_id)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now there is no alternative way:
The [Checkin endpoint](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/checkins/checkins) requires authentication, it will return the [data](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/checkin) you are looking for.

Foursquare requires you to act as a user (via [OAuth](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth)) to get user related information.

The only thing that does not require authentication is the [Venues Platform](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/venues), but you cannot get information about checkins from it, just number of people who checked in a place.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for the reply. But if I have the checkin id, can I use that to retrieve the checkin details via https://api.foursquare.com/v2/checkins/CHECKIN_ID while I act as a user? (I have tried and the system returns the message "Cannot view this checkin (must be friends with this user or provide valid signature).") I wonder what does it mean by "Provide valid signature"? (I have used the oauth_token)

Comment: I actually never worked with this endpoint, but the error explains itself - you must either be the friend or the user or have a signature. the signature is appended to the social feed (twitter in your case). Look at https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/checkins/checkins for more information.